# Problema com a forma de geração de ID no banco de dados

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Tenho um projeto feito com spring boot com banco de dados **postgres** onde uso Hibernate/JPA para mapear as entidades.

Só que cometi um erro ao definir a geração dos IDs das tabelas com `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` quando na verdade deveria ter usado `IDENTITY`.

Agora tenho diversos registros no banco com a contagem zuada.

Vamos supor que eu tenho um projeto com 3 tabelas usando o `IDENTITY`:

```
Tabela_1: id: 1, 2, 3

Tabela_2: id: 1, 2, 3

Tabela_3: id: 1, 2, 3
```

Agora usando o `AUTO`:

```
Tabela_1: id: 1, 2, 3

Tabela_2: id: 4, 5, 6

Tabela_3: id: 7, 8, 9
```

Como podem ver as tabelas sempre pega o último Id gerado e dar continuidade quando se usa o `AUTO`, hoje já tenho tabela com a contagem altíssima por conta disso.

Alguém sabe como posso corrigir isso, ou se tem algum comando pra banco (postgres) que possa corrigir isso e redefinir toda contagem de IDs sem perdes os relacionamentos?

Procurei na internet mas não encontrei nada parecido com meu caso, desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O `hibernate` possui 4 tipos de estratégias: (AUTO, IDENTITY, SEQUENCE, TABLE);

1. AUTO -> Caso omita a configuração o hibernate irá utiliza-la como padrão. No caso do `POSTGRES`, esse tipo cria uma sequence no banco de nome `hibernate_sequence` e essa sequence será utilizada para todas as tabelas onde você omitir a configuração. Ex.:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table
   public class A {
      @Id
      private Long id;
      private String nome;
   }

   @Entity
   @Table
   public class B {
      @Id
      private Long id;
      private String nome;
   }
   ```

> **Ao persistir um item do tipo A e logo em seguida persistir um do tipo B: A.getId() == 1 e B.getId() == 2 e assim sucessivamente**

2. IDENTITY -> Definindo essa estratégia o hibernate gerenciará automaticamente as inserções através de campo serial. Ex.:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table
   public class A {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
      private String nome;
   }

   @Entity
   @Table
   public class B {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
      private String nome;
   }
   ```

> **Ao persistir um item do tipo A e logo em seguida persistir um do tipo B: A.getId() == 1 e B.getId() == 1 o hibernate irá gerenciar a numeração através da coluna serial**

3. SEQUENCE -> Definindo essa estratégia, você é obrigado a criar o sequence para gerenciamento do incremento. Ex.:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table
   public class A {
      @Id
      @SequenceGenerator(name= "SeqA", sequenceName= "sq_tipo_a")         
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SeqA")
      private Long id;
      private String nome;
   }

   @Entity
   @Table
   public class B {
      @Id
      @SequenceGenerator(name= "SeqB", sequenceName= "sq_tipo_b")         
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SeqB")
      private Long id;
      private String nome;
   }
   ```

> **Ao persistir um item do tipo A e logo em seguida persistir um do tipo B: A.getId() == 1 e B.getId() == 1 isso devido a criação de sequences distintos para cada tabela (Tabela A -> sq_tipo_a e Tabela B -> sq_tipo_b).**

4. TABLE -> Definindo essa estratégia, você é obrigado a criar uma tabela para gerenciamento do incremento. Ex.:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table
   public class A {
      @Id
      @TableGenerator(name= "tbl_gen_a", table= "ids_a")         
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="tbl_gen_a")
      private Long id;
      private String nome;
   }

   @Entity
   @Table
   public class B {
      @Id
      @TableGenerator(name= "tbl_gen_b", table= "ids_b")         
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="tbl_gen_b")
      private Long id;
      private String nome;
   }
   ```

> Lembrando que isso é o básico de cada estratégia e você pode se aprofundar para um melhor entendimento do assunto como por exemplo a questão de performance. Sobre corrigir creio que não será possível após a criação das tuplas, desconheço um ferramenta com essa capacidade.